# how to download/uplaod file over HTTPS using Indy 10 and OpenSSL in delphi?

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, sftp, indy10

I wish I download a file using Indy.
My problem connecting to SSL.
Please help me to do this using HTTPS or SFTP.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdFTP1);
  IdFTP1.UseTLS:=utUseRequireTLS;
  IdFTP1.DataPortProtection:=ftpdpsPrivate;
  IdFTP1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  IdFTP1.Username := 'ftp';
  IdFTP1.Password := '123';
  IdFTP1.Port:=21;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.StartSSL;
  try
    IdFTP1.Connect;
    IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  finally
    IdFTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: DO NOT call `StartSSL()` manually.  Indy will call it automatically when appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You do it correctly (except the fact that you free component which you don't create in the same code). The same is for HTTPS.

```
IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
IdHTTP1.Get('https://...');
```

Just note that you need OpenSSL libraries
https://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/SSL.zip
or any version you want from
https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Also there is a difference between SFTP and FTPS.
Indy's IdFTP supports SSL (FTPS). It can't work with SFTP (FTP using SSH).
If you want to use SFTP, you have to use alternative commercial component
https://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-sftp.php

You should specify any error if it shows one. It is probably only that SSL libraries are missing.
If you don't know how to download/upload file, there are methods for that

```
IdFTP1.Put (upload)
IdFTP1.Get (download)

IdHTTP1.Put/Post (upload)
IdHTTP1.Get (download)
```

You will need TIdMultiPartFormDataStream from unit "IdMultipartFormData" for HTTP Post to upload files

Comment: FYI, if you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, you do not need to manually assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to `TIdHTTP` to use HTTPS.  See [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.EN.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is one example

```
function HttpGetFile(sUrl, sFile: String) : Boolean;
var
  GetData : TFileStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    GetData := TFileStream.Create(sFile, fmOpenWrite or fmCreate);
    try
        //IdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '';
        //IdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
        //IdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := '';
        //IdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := '';
        //IdHTTP.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;

        //IdHTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
        //IdHTTP.Request.Pragma := 'no-cache';
        //IdHTTP.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
        //IdHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en';
        //IdHTTP.Request.Referer := sTargetUrl;
        //NOTE needs files ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll
        if (bSecure) and ( FileExists( ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'ssleay32.dll')) 
       then begin
          IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method := 
           sslvSSLv23;
          IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions :=
           [sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
          IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
          sTargetUrl := HTTPS+UPLOAD_URL;
        end
        else begin
          IdHTTP.IOHandler := nil;
          sTargetUrl := HTTP+UPLOAD_URL;      
        end;
          IdHTTP.Get(sUrl, GetData);

      Result := (IdHTTP.ResponseCode = 200);
    finally
      GetData.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary do 
         ShowMessage(E.message);
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
         ShowMessage(E.message);
    on E: EIdConnClosedGracefully do
         ShowMessage(E.message);
    on E: EIdSocketError do
         ShowMessage(E.message);
    on E: EIdException do
         ShowMessage(E.message);
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Setting the `SSLOptions.Method` property automatically sets the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property, and vice versa.  You do not need to set them both in code. You should stick with just `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` and let Indy manage `SSLOptions.Method` internally.